# How to migrate tables in nodes from D6 to D7, created with the tablefield module

Tags: 7, migrations

I am 90% done with my migration from D6 to D7. The last thing to figure out is how to map a table in certain nodes, created with the tablefield module in D6, into a table in D7, also created with tablefield. Just mapping the fields does not do the trick.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_D7_table', 'field_D6_table');
```

With the above mapping there are no error messages, the table is just empty after the migration. I can see that the data is stored in serialized form in the legacy database. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Tablefield does not currently include migration support - there is a patch to add it at https://www.drupal.org/node/2317245. If you try out the patch and report on your results there, you may help move it forward.

Comment: After applying the patch I added a row in my hook_migrate_api for the new tablefield fieldhandler (MigrateTableFieldHandler) and then it was possible to map the fields as usual. In my specific case I have to deal with the fact that the D6 tablefield module was modified to have draggable rows and only 2 columns, so I still have some work to do before I can use it though.

Comment: I shoud add too, that it was possible to migrate the tablefield content with a simple "prepare()" function, without the patch:
 'public function prepare($entity, $row) {
    if(!empty($row->field_D6_field[0])){
   $entity->field_D7_field['und'][0]['value'] = $row->field_D6_field[0];
  }'

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used tablefield before myself, so don't know whatever special internal structure the field arrays may have, but from that (given that Migrate's default field handler assumes a 'value' default key) I would have expected a simple

`$this->addFieldMapping('field_D7_field', 'field_D6_field');`

to work.

Comment: Yes, after applying the patch the simple mapping you suggest works fine.